# ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?

Tags: java, android, listview

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this, but I can't figure out how to implement it. My `OnItemClickListener` was disabled somehow on my `ListView` rows, because I have an `ImageButton` in the row layout, which takes over the focus. There have been numerous questions I've found, but none of them have gotten me anywhere.

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097643/layout-question-onitemclicklistener-not-working-now) question, but I couldn't really make heads or tails of it. I just need a way to get the rows clickable so that I can detect when a row is pressed. Long press and focus work fine.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Instead of an *OnItemClickListener*, add an *OnClickListener* to each of your views returned from your adapter. You'll need to use `setItemsCanFocus` setting up your list:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
list.setAdapter(new DoubleClickAdapter(this));
list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

and then in your *Adapter*'s `getView`, this will yield a clickable row. The button is assumed to be in the inflated xml.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.cell, null);
    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("touched").show();
        }

    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to recycle views! Use the convertView, do not inflate a new one every time.

Comment: I had basically done that, though I feel like I had problems doing something. I'll try it out again, maybe it was just a stupid mistake.

Comment: Okay, can anyone explain *why* the ListView controls aren't working as advertised?  I've had this same issue too and this solution works though the response time on touch is not good.

Comment: Old question I know but you can also create the onclicklistner in the   "newView" method of your adapter instead. This will save this process being called every time the user scrolls the list

Comment: This is not an ideal solution if you still want your whole row to be clickable, you should use http://stackoverflow.com/a/4518810/9636

Comment: this does not work if i do it in `newView()` of an extended `CursorAdaptor`, instead of in a `getView()`. What's wrong?

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now, and I really need help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Answer (score 53):

set your `ImageButton`'s attribute:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Because `AbsListView.onTouchEvent` check `child.hasFocusable()`.

Comment: Works great for TextViews. Not so much for Buttons.

Comment: If you use android:inputType for textview, you should remove it also.

Comment: Much better option that the answer with the award.  Register a single listener, and deal with it.  Less memory to boot.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now, and I really need help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Comment: Adding another finding - Dont use "View" widget, use ImageView  or as applicable

Answer (score 10):

I've tested the following solution on SDK levels 8 and 16.

In `getView()`

```
setFocusable(false);
setClickable(false);
```

rather than setting them true in the Adapter's `getView()` does what I think the original question wanted, and means that an `OnItemClickListener` gets called, provided that an `OnClickListener` is not set in `getView()`.

I'm assuming that anything you can do in an View's `OnClickListener` you can do just as easily in a `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener`.
(`setOnClickListener` on a View implicitly sets the view to be clickable, which prevents the `ListView`'s corresponding `OnItemClickListener` getting called, apparently.)

The behaviour is as one would expect, in terms of the `ImageButton`'s visual state when the item is pressed or rolled over.

The solution is a slight illusion, in that it is the list item that's being pressed not the `ImageButton` itself, so if the button doesn't occupy whole list item, clicking somewhere else in the item will still make the button's drawable state reflect the click. Same for focus. That might be a price worth paying.

Comment: If your ListView row has multiple clickable items, you can probably achieve exactly what you want by setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the top level list item layout, and not setting an `OnClickListener` on the view that you return from getView(). Setting `OnClickListener`s on the individual items will still work.

Comment: This solution also worked for me. In my case  I was not getting clicked event in OnItemClickListener when RadioButton was clicked.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now, and I really need help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Answer (score 7):

This will definitely work. Add this to the layout definition.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Found the solution [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/08/focus-problems-with-list-rows-and.html)

Answer (score 5):

One alternative to setting an `OnClickListener` for every view is to NOT use an `ImageButton` - use an `ImageView` instead. The `ImageView` can still send events to an `OnClickListener` and won't take over the focus.

Answer (score 5):

best way to do is this:

```
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

set these properties for that `Imagebutton` and try.
I

Answer (score 4):

For my version of this problem, the issue was that I had set my `TextView` object to `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`.  When I removed this line the issue of the list not being clickable was gone.  Looks like a nasty little bug.

Also, I'm still able to use the `android:minLines/android:maxLines` properties with no problem, so it's not a big issue.  Just not the solution I expected.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now, and I really need help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108940/why-cant-i-remove-an-item/35109304#35109304

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution which worked for me you can try to extend your adapter from `BaseAdapter` (iso implementing `ListAdapter` interface)

Answer (score 1):

The following line solved the issue in my project:

```
<TextView ... android:textIsSelectable="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put This code   `ImageView nextpage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);` instead of `ImageButton` . now the list item is active

Answer (score 0):

I have sub-classed `ImageButton` and `setFocusable="false"` in layout definition didn't work for me. It solved calling `setFocusable(false)` in constructor of subclass.

Answer (score -1):

Using a `ScrollView` can prevent the `onItemClickListener` from receiving the input.

Hope this helps anyone.