# Android list view on click

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view with 15 items. When I click on any item I want to change the screen(Intent). how can I change the activity on item selected in android?
any tutorial or source code?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Knowing a click occurred, determining which item was clicked, or starting a new activity?

Comment: please, do a little bit of research yourself before asking a question. This same question (both the item clicked and the change activity) is answered more than 10 times just in SO.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ListView`'s `setOnItemClickListener`, and start an new Activity in your implementation of this method. Following is sample code:

```
myListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id){
        // Start your Activity according to the item just clicked.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the selected answer in [ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

If you also need code examples to change activity, head to https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html and start reading.

```
// Prepare intent
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);

// start activity
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SCHEDULE);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hiihih",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
```