# When I add a view to a ListView Item, this Item reacts no longer properly

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, onitemclicklistener

I want,a new `View` appears in my `ListView` `Item`, if I click this Item like this, where (1) and (2) are clicks

[image]

and I can do it, but when I want to click again this `Item`, i.e. to hide that new `View`, then `Item`click reacts no longer in the way it should do.

I perform the `add` View Operation in my `onItemClickListener` right to the properly position

My code is the following

```
...
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onItemClick:: BEGIN");

            switch (position) {
                case 0 : 
                    Log.i("TAG", "onItemClick:: before addTitle");                      
                    showFieldList(view);
                    Log.i("TAG", "onItemClick:: after  addTitle");
                break;              
                ...                 
            }

            Log.i("TAG", "onItemClick:: END");
        }
});
...
```

I tried to show the behaviour in my `Log`  and after the first Click I can see my `Log` Entry "TAG" with the values

`onItemClick:: BEGIN`

`onItemClick:: before addTitle`

`onItemClick:: after addTitle`

`onItemClick:: BEGIN`

but the next clicks show nothing and as said, that `Item` doesn't react anymore but I can see instead my client_adapter `LOG` and just the entries of `getGroupView` Method are shown when I click on `Item`.

I just wanted to remark too, that it also behaves like this, if I attach the `OnGroupExpand/OnGroupCollapse/OnGroupClick Listeners` of ExpandableListView.

Sum up: I have a `ListView` and if I click the first Item, this one expand to show an `ExpandableListView` and if I'click again, this should be collapsed but this doesn't behave like this, so that the `ExpandableListView` assumes the control over entire Item.

**Can anyone tell me, why the `item` loses control of clicks and this is won by the `ExpandableListView` FieldList?
Thank you in advance!**

Rest of code

```
    private View showFieldList(View view) {

        // Retrieving Item Layout. (= view Layout)
        RelativeLayout item_layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relLayoutDrawer);

        // Retrieving "title" Element
        TextView title_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        View row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.field_list, null);

        // Getting Field names
        Resources res = getResources();
        String fields = res.getString(R.string.fields);         

        client = (ExpandableListView)row.findViewById(R.id.field_expandable_list);

        client.setFocusable(false); //<< ADDED TO WORK  

        client_adapter = new ClientAdapter(context, fields);



        // When I comment this Line, `onItemClick` works
        // if not, then client_adapter assummes control

        client.setAdapter(client_adapter); 

        // Setting "Subtitle" under "title" aligning both left borders
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, title_tv.getId());
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, title_tv.getId());     
        item_ayout.addView(row, params);    
    }
```

Here my `drawer_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/metallic_silver"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try calling view.requestLayout() after item_ayout.addView(row, params);

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use an ExpandableListView nested in a ListView? If it is because of the 3 level depth, you could get the same with the Expandable list only.

Comment: @momo Yes, the main reason is Design Specification. It must be like this.

Comment: @IllegalArgument I have tested but successless, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

I properly wrote again `onCollapsedGroupListener`, `onExpandedGroupListener` and `onClickedGroupListener` and I added the next line to the last code

```
client = (ExpandableListView)row.findViewById(R.id.field_expandable_list);
...
client.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Now my trouble is to populate the nested `ExpandablewListView`, I have opened a new thread with a Bounty (50). Group is properly populated but not the children. Each time, it should call `getChildView` of this nested  ExpandableListView`, It calls `getView` of Main `ListView`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379164/getchildview-gets-not-called

Answer (score 2):

The problem exists because you have `ExpandableListView` nested in your `ListView`. When `ExpandableListView` is hidden, only `ListView` receives `onClick` events, but when it appears it consumes all the `onClick` events, therefore your `ListView` doesn't react on clicking anymore.

You can either follow this topic: [ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

Or just go for approach offered by momo in one of comments - using only `ExpandableListView` with just more levels of depth.

Comment: Piotr but I didn't attach any Listener to the ExpandableListView. I have developed ListViews with customized Items (Linear and Relative Layouts with ImageViews, Buttons, etc) and I always had to attach their Listeners, in order that they react. Thx

Comment: @Gödel77 I think it consumes the events anyway. They're just not delegated to any specific `Listener`.