# How to implement Android ListView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and OnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` with ChoiceMode as `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` which is rendering each item with a checkbox to select.

```
List<Note> values = datasource.getAllNotes();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I want to implement `OnItemClickListener` to view the selected item details.

The problem is when I select an item, in addition to getting the checkbox checked the onItemClick() callback method also getting triggered where I am showing the selected Item details in AlertDialog.

How can I change the behavior so that item will be checked only when I click on checkbox and when I click on item text then `onItemClick()` should be fired?

Comment: normal google search http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/android-multiple-selection-listview/

Comment: seems to be the answer to your question.
[ListView OnItemClickListener...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2369327/2335224

Comment: @arashjavan He is not using a custom adapter..

Comment: @Arun Kumar, did you read my question and what is there in that blog post?

Comment: I think I may need to follow the approach in  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html 14.2. Tutorial: Domain Model and Rows interaction